# matlab interpolation for calculating volume within a given area

Tags: matlab

I have some depth measurements and corresponding area at each depth of a water column:

```
depth = [0,2,4,6,7,9,10];
Area = [2000,1890,1873,1654,1523,1433,1200];

figure(1);
plot(Area,depth);set(gca,'ydir','reverse');
```

I want to calculate the volume of water between each depth indicated and then calculating the entire volume of water from this. Firstly I have interpolated the depth and area values to improve the accuracy of the calculation:

```
dz = 0.1;
newD = min(depth):dz:max(depth);
newA = interp1(depth,Area,newD);

figure(2);
plot(newA,newD);set(gca,'ydir','reverse');
```

Where would I go from here for calculating the volume of water between each of the depths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get volume you multiply area by height. Hence, since your dz is constant, to get water volumes at chosen depths you need to multiply

```
newA*dz
```

To get the total volume you sum it up

```
sum(newA*dz)
```

Your calculations are done assuming linear change of water area with depth (that's what you achieve with interp1). I am sure you can manage to integrate a linear function analytically instead of using your current approach. You can easily get an exact number.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to multiply the areas by the total depth, not the depth step:

```
volume = newA.*newD;
totalVolume = sum(volume);
```

Comment: Your answer is not correct. Kate wants to compute the water volume "the volume of water between each depth indicated", which I assume means for every dz. Your answer is wrong because you multiply water area at given depth by that depth. This does not take into account the fact that the water area **changes** with depth. So effectively you compute integrated water volume from the **surface** to a given depth with the assumption that the water area is constant. It is not, hence your answer is wrong.